# Choosing a GIS which imports a list of stage addresses, calculates the route, allows to modify and export it

Tags: routing, database, business, address

I'm new to GISs. I'm searching for a **GIS** to meet following requirements.

I have a **list of street addresses** [A,B,C,D,E,...], with additional information associated (basically which orders to deliver at each address and to which customer), available in a DB table (DBMS: DB2 for i Series) or .xls file.

I need to show these addresses on a **map** and calculate the **route** among them. Not the global best route, but the route that touches each point maintaining the order given for them. Then the user should **modify this order** if necessary (e.g.  [A,E,C,B,D,...]) and the route should be recalculated.

As **output** I need to write the points in the new order on a **DB table** (also with customer info etc. for each record). I also need to print a PDF with the map and route instructions for the truck driver.

I considered MapPoint, but counld't succedd with automatic route calculation for the imported addresses (to calculate a route I have to manually add each point). Google Maps API seems promising, but I don't know how to do many of the operations above.

Any hint on which GIS could fit? Both web-based or desktop applications are welcome. Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have a budget?

Comment: Let's say we are oriented to a relatively simple desktop/web application, simply with maps, routes and integration with DB. No need of advanced geospatial information management. So the budget could be max 200 euros per license

Comment: Neither DB2 nor .xls are a good starting point for open source GIS. With 200 eur per license you won't get anything else I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this solution:

- I prepare list of addresses and their additional information as an **.xls file**
- I **wrote an add-in** for **Microsoft MapPoint** (it's easy using Visual Studio*) that

  - imports the .xls and puts the addresses on the map
  - calculate the route among them
  - give some additional instruments to the user for changing stops order
  - when user is ready, exports the list of stops to the **DB**, with arrival and departure times for every stop in the route it just calculated

---

***Creating an addin for MapPoint** (some names could be incorrect, I've guessed them, because my Visual Studio is not in English ;D):

- launch Visual Studio (as administrator) > View > Tools
- right click on Tools > Choose elements... > COM components > check "Microsoft MapPoint Control x.x" > OK
- right click on Tools > Show all > General > now you should find "Microsoft MapPoint Control x.x"
- File > New > Project... > look for something like "Shared add-in" > give a name to the project > OK > check only on "Microsoft MapPoint" > straight on to the end
- Esplore solutions > right click on References > Add reference... > "Microsoft MapPoint x.x Object Library (Europe)" > OK
- Esplore solutions > open *Connect.cs* and write addin source code; the best place to put code that need to be executed on addin loading is `OnConnection`
- build (MapPoint must be closed) and test (2 alternatives):

  - launch MapPoint
  - right click on setup project > Install > straight on to the end > launch MapPoint